# Codeinginter : joining 2 tables based on 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have two database tables `quotations`  and `garag`. Both tables have lat, lng field .

I have to show quotation to nearby garages based on certain defined radius.

for this i have to take **lat,lng**  from quotations table and match it with the **lat,lng** of garages table

i can get nearby garages using following query in CI

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM garage HAVING distance < 25";
$result = $this->db->query($sql) ;
```

but i am not sure how do i related it with quotations requested lat , lng

can you please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Q.*
FROM garage g
LEFT JOIN quotes q
ON SQRT(SQUARE(ABS(q.lat - g.lat)) + SQUARE(ABS(q.lng - g.lng))) <= @MaxDistanceInDegrees
WHERE g.id = @GarageID
```

This should work. Note that if you have a large database, this problem becomes significantly more complicated, and you'll likely need to create some sort of grid system to mitigate the n^2 issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this query on my side but I think it will help to achieve the result which you want. I am adding two technique here.

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*') // Add your require column name as you want
    ->from('garage as g')
    ->join('distance as d1', 'd1.lat = g.lat', 'left outer')
    ->join('distance as d2', 'd2.lng = g.lng', 'left outer')              
    //->where('g.column', $variable)  
    ->get();

// OR Try this way using and
->join('distance as d1', 'd1.lat = g.lat AND d1.lng = g.lng');
```